# Ionic deploy ignores newly installed cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, deployment, ionic-framework

When deploying a new release of an Ionic app using [Ionic Deploy](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-overview), it is possible to update a mobile device thanks to `Ionic.Deploy().update`. Everything works fine except when you want to introduce a new cordova plugin.

Let's say I want to implement a new feature which requires to use the device's camera, I would probably install `cordova-plugin-camera` and add it to my `package.json`. However once you deploy this enhanced version using Ionic Deploy, and after you actually update the app from the device itself, the new plugin is not installed and you can't use the new feature. Leading to silent failures all over the place.

Now the question is:
**is there a way to force Ionic Deploy to install new dependencies remotely?**

Comment: The official doc says that ionic deploy is suitable for apps that dont require any binary change. Dont you think adding a new plugin is a genuine binary change in the app?

Comment: I didnt notice it was mentioned. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Have posted the answer. Accept the same if it was useful so that it can be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [official Ionic documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-overview), Please find the following excerpt as follows:

> "Ionic Deploy lets you update your app on demand, for any changes that **do not require binary modifications**, saving you days, or even weeks, of wait time."

As per you requirement, introducing a new plugin is an obvious binary change. So as per my understanding, currently you cannot use Ionic Deploy in this case.